# Manipulate URLs while loading external website through Apache as a proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I own a website foo.com and want to load external content from bar.com when I visit foo.com/barcontent using Apache webserver. In addition, I want to stay under foo.com/barcontent all time
My config looks like this

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLProxyVerify none
  SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
  SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
  ProxyPass /barcontent/ https://bar.com/
  ProxyPassReverse /barcontent/ https://bar.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

It works with charme. Entering foo.com/barcontent displays all the content of bar.com/.
BUT... every link under foo.com/barcontent points to bar.com so when I follow a link under foo.com/barcontent, it will redirect to bar.com and doesn't stay on foo.com/barcontent
foo.com/barcontent/abc/def maps 1:1 to bar.com/abc/def so that the proxy mode is working but I want to replace all links with the target url with /barcontent.
I think, I miss some rewrite rule or something like that. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy_html active in that Apache?

Comment: Or everything needs to be declared as relative paths, which is a pain.

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes, mod is running.

Comment: oh wait, the pages served by bar.com have full path, and not relative paths?  Explanation.  **foo.com/barcontent/something.html**, is served by **bar.com/barcontent/something.com**.  Does the page something.com contain `href="http://bar.com/somedir/somethingelse.com"` ?  It should only contain `href="/somedir/somethingelse.com"`.  This way the new request is sent back like `http://foo.com/somedir/somethingelse.com` and stays within foo.com domain.

Comment: bar.com provides pull paths. e.g. bar.com/something.html. At the moment, foo.com/barcontent/something.html is calling internally bar.com/something.html